# In a fixed voltage case, why does inserting a dielectric increase the energy by a factor of $K$?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electric-circuits, capacitance, dielectric

When inserting a dielectric, the electric field will do a positive work, and it will lose energy to attract the dielectric.

by comparison, when dielectric is inserted in a charge-constant case, this will consume $\Delta U=U_0(1-1/K)$ J and in both cases the dielectric must be attracted, however if it consumes the same amount of energy, this means that the final energy of the system when $V = constant$ will  must be equal to  $U_f  =  k U_0 + (1- 1/K) U_0$

Must the battery provide this $\Delta U$ and provide it to the dielectric in order to have the final energy of the capacitor equals to $k U_0$? Or that is wrong?

Plus does this value of $\Delta U$  also stand for the case that I am explaining, or it is wrong because the charge is not constant?

Comment: Well, the charge isn’t constant, so...

Comment: so how do we compute delta U and compare it ? I am really stuck

Comment: Compare the energy of a capacitor at voltage V with different dielectric constants. Don’t over think it.

Answer (score 0):

you might have thought since electric field inside dielectric is $\frac{E}{K}$

so work done would be----$\frac{E d}{K}$ = $\frac{Uo}{K}$ (d- separation between plates of capacitor)

$Uo/K$ is the work done to move a  charge $Q$i inside a dielectric slab, and it is equal to $Q$i$V$ of battery connected, also $Uo$ was the work done earlier to move test charge across plates of capacitor without dielectric slab and it was  equal to $QV$ as across
plates of capacitor potential difference remains same when there is dielectric medium in between or not (note that $Q$i is different  charge, because when dielectric slab is inserted capacitance changes but voltage remains same so the charge on capacitor must change)

the external work needed to be done in order to insert dielectric slab, it is not provided by battery, it is work needed to be done externally( your equation of $\Delta U$ is however incorrect)

what we are talking about is potential energy stored inside capacitor it is not equal to
$QV$ (the work a battery does to move charge $Q$ across circuit) it is equal to **work done to move a single plate of capacitor from zero to separation d with respect to other plate at rest**

$1/2(QV)$ or [ $1/2(CV^2)$ ]--------1, (*as rest of energy becomes heat)*

you must have idea about these concepts

since capacitance when there is dielectric medium in between Is $KC$, and potential energy stored is  $1/2(KCV^2)$ from 1 [***this is your answer***]

(Your equation contains variable $Uo$ and $Uo/K$ is the work performed by battery
to move respective charges across $V$ potential difference provided by battery, **not the potential energy when  a dielectric slab in between)**